# MakePoint return empty result

Tags: sql, spatialite

I have a spatialite database with longitutade and latitude colums as text:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude FROM mytable1 LIMIT 3;
54.475|9.0422222222222
52.398055555556|13.733888888889
49.940277777778|11.576388888889
```

When I try to create a geometry from them with them MakePoint it results in emtpy values:

```
spatialite> SELECT MakePoint(longitude, latitude, 4326) FROM mytable1 LIMIT 3;



spatialite>
```

On another table with lat/lon columns as text it's working. Any idea why?

**Solution**:
cast lon/lat text columns to real like

```
UPDATE mytable2 SET geom = MakePoint(cast(longitude as real), cast(latitude as real), 4326)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the case where it's working with columns as TEXT (I only get NULLs). Could you post an example?

Comment: damn my mistake. On mytable1 I already cast the latitude, longitude columns from text to real. On mytable2 they are as text.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer and accept it so it can help others?